# My C program creates files of 4Gb on a raspberri pi when they should have a size of 8 bytes

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a C code compiled with GCC in Ubuntu 14.04 that among other things, creates a file, write 8 bytes, and then closes it. The code works fine in my i7 64 bits pc. The problem is that when I compile and execute my code on a 32 bits architecture (raspberry pi 2 with raspbian) this operation creates a file of size 4294967304 bytes. I don't know what's wrong. The strange thing is that my program creates 3 files in the same way that should be empty but their size is 4 Gb each, and my available memory is only 8 Gb. This leads me to believe that I'm breaking the file system (ext4) but I don't know why. The code is this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int outImpFile = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE | O_CREAT, 0);
    long long int imp = 89;
    write(outImpFile, &imp, sizeof(long long int));
    close(outImpFile);
}
```

When I open the created file with ghex I only see 8 bytes, but when I use hexdiff there are many empty bytes at the beginning and my written 8 bytes at the end.

Comment: How do you check the size? And why do you call `open` with the `O_LARGEFILE` flag?

Comment: I checked the size with dolphin, nautilus and ls -l, all these return the same.

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)? Did you use the `gdb` debugger and `strace` on your Raspberry Pi? And why do you need `O_LARGEFILE`? You practically don't have enough space on your SD card for that to be useful!

Comment: The O_LARGEFILE flag was me in my despair trying different options, but without this flag I get the same result

Comment: Oh and you have checked the returns from all the function you call? To make sure that none of them fails?

Comment: @b-612 But you do pass `&imp` instead of `imp` to the `write` function, right?

Comment: Also, `write` returns the number of bytes written as another opportunity to check, which you didn't use.

Comment: @b-612: You forgot to show us the `lseek()` commands your actual code contains.

Comment: @b-612, [edit] your question to post a complete and compilable program that exhibits the behaviour. Remove anything irrelevant from it, leave just the smallest code that still has the issue. That way it's easier to see what the problem is or might be.

Comment: you're right Ivan, I pass &imp instead of imp, I corrected that in the question.

Comment: 4294967304 = 0x100000008 = 8 + 2**32. It is almost certain that the OP has omitted commands that seek the file position to the 4 GiB mark prior to the `write()` command. (An alternative is that they are using `pwrite()` or `pwritev()` instead, either with a 4 GiB offset, or omitting the parameter altogether so the 4 GiB offset is just a happenstance due to a severe programming bug.)

Comment: I compiled using MSVC (without the `O_LARGEFILE` which it doesn't know, and including `io.h` instead of `stdlib.h`) and it creates a file sized 8 bytes, content `59 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` (hex). If the file exists, `open` returns `-1` and then crashes if that result is not trapped. I also compiled it with MS's `_underscore` versions which has the same behaviour.

Comment: If you do not actually intend to write 4GB files, consider using the Standard C file functions (`fopen`, `fwrite`)

Comment: –1 for fake code. This is not the program exhibiting the issue.

Answer (score 7):

The cause of the strange error is the lack of correct headers, specifically `<unistd.h>`. This causes the parameters to [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to be of incorrect types, especially the `count` parameter.

Try this corrected version of your program:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long long int value = 89;
    ssize_t n;
    int descriptor;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: %s FILENAME\n\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    descriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (descriptor == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    n = write(descriptor, &value, sizeof value);
    if (n != sizeof value) {
        if (n == -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Partial write (%zd bytes).\n", argv[1], n);
        close(descriptor);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (close(descriptor)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Error closing file.\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%zd bytes written successfully to '%s'.\n", n, argv[1]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Always, **always** enable warnings when compiling code. With GCC, I use `gcc -Wall -O2` (for both warnings and compiler-optimized results). I warmly recommend you do the same. If you save the above as `fixed.c`, then compile it using

```
gcc -Wall -O2 fixed.c -o fixed-example
```

and run it using

```
./fixed-example output-file
```

If you need to compile against e.g. the math library, include the options just before the `-o` flag; i.e. `gcc -Wall -O2 fixed.c -lm -o fixed-example` for the above program. The order of options do matter for GCC.

Comment: You might also address his use of a nonportable data type in a binary file used cross-platform. His long long int happens to be 8 bytes on both today, but not always. He should be using `uint64_t` or similar.

Comment: Are you sure this is OP's problem? Types are such that a call without prototype should be valid.

Comment: @R..: The arm-linux-gnueabihf ABI used supports both 32 and 64-bit word sizes; the exact definitions and promotion rules followed here (including the fact that GCC passes parameters in registers) are complicated. I do believe that *if* the code shown in the question does exhibit the behaviour described, then not including `<unistd.h>` either causes a type mismatch for the `size_t` type, or causes a completely different syscall wrapper to be called instead (likely `writev()`).

Comment: @R..: However, the most likely case here is, in my own opinion (which is admittedly often wrong), is that OP for some strange reason is unwilling to show the actual code and commands that generated the odd results. They perhaps found a bug of their own making, and rather than help others avoid that same pitfall, they decided that their self-perceived [*"face"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_%28sociological_concept%29) is more important than anything else, and are willfully leaving others to work out a problem that does not exist in the form described.

Comment: (make that `pwrite()`, not `writev()`.)

Comment: ABI isn't relevant. Aside from a call with no declaration at all being invalid C, calls without a prototype are well-defined as long as the actual expressions passed as args have the right types after default promotions. As far as I can tell, they do in OP's code.

Comment: Also ARM is a 32-bit arch. There is no EABI variant with 64-bit sizes.

Comment: @R..: Bullshit. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARMv8-A) for the details on the 64/32-bit ARMv8-A hardware architecture that applies here. It supports two different instruction sets, A32 and A64, A32 being the ARMv7 32-bit instruction set. The Linux kernel in Raspbian supports both for userspace code; and that is at the core here: [`size_t` is 64-bit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch08s02.html) even for A32 (Raspbian follows AAPCS64-LP64).

Comment: @NominalAnimal: That's `aarch64` which is a completely different architecture as far as the compiler is concerned. `arm-linux-gnueabihf` is 32-bit ARM not aarch64; the latter is `aarch64-linux-gnu`. In any case it's not relevant to this not being OP's problem.